# Load data from host machine to docker hive container

Tags: python, hadoop, docker, hive

I have a csv file in my host machine and I have a docker VM. I want to upload the data from the csv file in my host to the VM. I am using python's hive_service library to connect to and make queries. However, I am stuck as to how to put data into the VM. 
For example the script below connects and is able to query hive but fails at the second query. I need to upload smpl.txt from my host machine to the docker vm

```
import sys

from hive_service import ThriftHive
from hive_service.ttypes import HiveServerException
from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

try:
  print "1111"
  transport = TSocket.TSocket("192.168.99.100", 10000)
  transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
  protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
  print "2222"
  client = ThriftHive.Client(protocol)
  transport.open()
  print "3333"

  client.execute("CREATE TABLE names (name string, value int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','")
  client.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './smpl.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE names")
  # client.execute("SELECT * FROM orders")
  # while (1):
  #   row = client.fetchOne()
  #   if (row == None):
  #     break
  #   print row

  #client.execute("SELECT * FROM r")
  # print client.fetchAll()
  print "4444"
  transport.close()
except Thrift.TException, tx:
  print '%s' % (tx.message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that file must already be in the docker VM, you can consider using [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/), which allows for copying a local file to a running container.

Using a library like [`pypi/docker-py/`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-py/), that would translate into:

```
c = docker.Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
                  version='1.12', timeout=10)
c.copy(container, resource)
```

Comment: Do you know where to copy the data / file in the Hive container and how to create the corresponding database / table?

Comment: Here it is, thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140046/initialize-cloudera-hive-docker-container-with-data