# Initialize Cloudera Hive Docker Container With Data

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, docker-compose, cloudera

I am running the Cloudera suite in a Docker Container using the image described here: https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/

I have the following configuration:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM cloudera/quickstart:latest
```

**Docker Compose file**

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  db-hive:
    container_name: mobydq-test-db-hive
    image: mobydq-test-db-hive
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db-hive/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 10000
    networks:
      - default
    hostname: quickstart.cloudera
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    command: ["/usr/bin/docker-quickstart"]

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mobydq-network
```

When the container start, I would like it creates automatically a new database, a table and populates it with data. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have found is to copy the content of the script `/user/bin/docker-quickstart` into a new shell script `entrypoint.sh`. Then I added the Create table and Insert statements directly in the `entrypoint.sh`.

Example here: https://github.com/ubisoft/mobydq/blob/master/test/db-cloudera/init/entrypoint.sh

Finally I run the command `entrypoint.sh` in the docker compose file instead of the quickstart script.

Comment: looks like the file moved to https://github.com/ubisoft/mobydq/blob/master/test/db-cloudera/init/entrypoint.sh